# Problem with permissions when syncing to sites directory

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, ln

Is there a way to symbolically link a directory using `ln` to my ~/Sites/ directory on OS X so that the permissions are correct so it may be viewed in a web browser when I'm doing web development on a local machine?

This is what I did `ln -s ~/code/web/yolkportfolio ~/Sites/yolkportfolio` I then `chmod 755` on the directory but it still isn't readable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the permissons on the link?

Comment: `755` are the permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my apache config. Here is what allowed it to work, just the `FollowSymLinks` rule.

```
<Directory "/Users/Joe/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

**1.** If you are running `apache` with a different user (not yours), and definitively want the `DocumentRoot` to point to some directory inside your home, you meed to change permissions to your home directory (defaults must be `750` or `700`) to `755`

I'd only recommend this if this is your laptop or your personal computer and no one else has access to it.

**2.** The first one is not an option but you still want the `DocumentRoot` inside your home, then you can change the user who runs `apache`. Edit its configuration file and look for directives `User` and `Group`.

**3.** Second one is still not an option, and still ... you want things inside your home. Use apache's mod_userdir. With the following configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root

        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
                AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Limit>
                <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Deny from all
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

This is the default configuration for Apache's mod_userdir on Debian. You will be able to access:

```
/home/your-username/public_html/*
```

on your browser at the following address:

```
http://somewhere/your-username/*
```

**4.** Finally, you could place `DocumentRoot` somewhere else (`/srv/www`, `/opt/www` or whatever) and setup permissions as needed.

Comment: I've done what you said with permissions but I'm still getting problems while trying to access the directory. I still get 403: Forbidden

Comment: Can you post your apache's config files ?

Comment: My apache config file may be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/56CZFUrp).

Comment: Post the exact command you used to change permissions

Comment: `chmod -R 755 ~/Sites/yolkportfolio/` which is symlinked to my `~/code` directory.

Comment: That is exactly your problem. You have `chmod`ed the directory that is inside your home, but the problem is your home's permissions. If you choose to change permissions, then `chmod 755 ~/` is what you want.